# Message list items need to start from bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, message, android-relativelayout

All I need is a linear or relative layout I programmatically add the items but they need to start from the bottom like message threads normally do how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a ListView or a RecyclerView, but if you have to use a non-collection friendly layout, I would go with LinearLayout, because I find it easier to setup in code. You just have to set its orientation to vertical and always add children views on position 0. For example, this would add 10 text views bottom to top:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    ll.addView(tv, 0);
}
```

And don't forget to wrap the LinearLayout into a scrolable container in case you have more elements than the screen can display.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I just tried this however it still appears at the top of the linear layout instead of the bottom is there something I possibly haven't done correctly other than what was just said?

Comment: I thought you meant the order of the child views needs to be 'newest on top'. But I guess what you need is if let's say there are only two children, you'd like them to show up on the bottom of the screen instead of the top. If this is what you want (and you still want to use a `LinearLayout` :-) ) you can set `android:gravity="bottom"` on the `LinearLayout` and `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrollView`

Comment: I tried using this too but the same effect it's ok though I solved it I have the scroll view wrpped in a relative layout the scrollviews height is wrap content and align parent bottom then it simply goes from bottom to top and when adding view I add it to 0 so that it's the bottom item. Thanks for your help!!!